# Using SVN, is there any way of warning a group of all files committed? (Tortoise SVN, to be more especific)

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, source-control-explorer

I'm new to all of this version control world and I wanna know if is there any option/add-on in TortoiseSVN, to add a icon or something to files which had been committed/updated into my SVN server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is a tool called [CommitMonitor](http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/CommitMonitor.html) which anyone can use to watch a repo, and show you all the commits and log messages along with them. There is even some basic filtering.

Comment: Thanks Stephen! I think this is what I was searching for.

Answer (score 4):

Don't know about tortoise but SVN support the hook concept. You can read here about a hook to send an email:

http://webonrails.com/2007/07/12/get-svn-commit-notification-right-into-your-inbox-by-using-svn-hook-post-commit/

Answer (score 2):

Not that I know of. The idea of SVN is that you don't need to know. You do your work, your peers do theirs, and at regular intervals you commit and update. At those points you resolve conflicts and move on.

Ema's post is dead on. If you want commit notifications, that's the way to go.

Comment: If I forget to get some files with an Update? As a human, I'd rather have any technology helping me to error less. :D
Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

We are successfully using Cruise Control. It's free and it even allows you to build the commited files so that you are also notified if a build succeeded or not.

This is done using a simple client app CCTray and you can also configure notifications by email.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's on by default, but in Explorer there is usually a green checkmark icon on files that have been committed and a red exclamation point on things that have been updated and not committed.

[image: Explorer icons]

Are you running Windows?
[image: Settings]

Comment: the icon overlays only show local modifications though. they give no indication of whether a file has changed in the repo or not since your last update. i agree with ema and qor72, that you dont NEED to know, you just make sure to update every once in a while.

Comment: I understand that.  The OP used "into the server", so I assumed he meant local changes. Glad it's resolved for him.